# copy and paste on excel without deleting cells current content

Tags: excel, cell, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to create a cell to build canned response emails in excel. I need to be able to paste text into a cell without deleting the information that already exists within that cell (and I would need to be able to do this repeatedly.) I am basically asking for help creating a single cell that has similar 'copy and paste' properties as a word doc. i.e. when I paste text into a cell it will insert the new text below previous text rather replacing the existing text with clipboard.

I could definitely use some help coding this in VBA. Please let me know if anything needs to be clarified! Thank you

Comment: grab the text you need, and in the destination cell don't paste, but rather `ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & 'whatever new text to add`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I wrote the code to do what you asked for, but I'm not sure if it is really what you need.**

Press `Alt+F11`

Double click on the worksheet you want this to work on (Left Side)

[image: Paste Code]

Paste in this code.

Note that this code will allow you to clear a cell by hitting Delete.

Otherwise, it would be difficult to delete it.

Note that this will essentially append any cell that you try to edit with your edit.

```
Dim currentVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If currentVal <> vbNullString And Target.Value <> vbNullString Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = currentVal & vbCrLf & Target.Value
    currentVal = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    currentVal = Target.Value
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then currentVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

How it works:

[image: Working]

Hopefully final edit to work with merged cells typing on mobile unable to test:

```
Dim currentVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If currentVal <> vbNullString And Target.Cells(1,1).Value <> vbNullString Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Use this to add an extra line instead
    Target.Cells(1,1).Value = currentVal & vbLf & vbLf & Target.Cells(1,1).Value
    'Target.Cells(1,1).Value = currentVal & vbLf & Target.Cells(1,1).Value
    currentVal = Target.Cells(1,1).Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    currentVal = Target.Cells(1,1).Value
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
currentVal = Target.Cells(1,1).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: user1274820, we have voted your answer to be undeleted as this is the solution which OP wants. Request you to not delete it please :)

Comment: Hey Scott, no worries - sure :) - feel free to let me know if you need any help

Comment: Yes. `vbCrLf` adds a new line, so you can just place an extra `& vbCrLf` after the current `vbCrLf` on the line `Target.Cells(1,1).Value = currentVal & vbCrLf & Target.Cells(1,1).Value` - It becomes `Target.Cells(1,1).Value = currentVal & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Target.Cells(1,1).Value` - as you might guess from the code, it just appends the new value with a `vbCrLf` character. I edited the code at the bottom so you can copy and paste if you want.

Comment: fwiw, the multi-line content in an excel cell uses a line feed (e.g. vbLF or Chr(10)), not a full carriage return (e.g. vbCRLF or Chr(13) & Chr(10)). Excel usually strips the Chr(13) out but sometimes it is left in (importing data for instance) and becomes a 'rogue ' character. I have no idea what will happen here but it might be wise to stick with the vbLF and not the vbCRLF.

Comment: This is because pressing enter is firing the `Worksheet_Change` event. You can either just not press enter and use the arrow keys to navigate away from the cell, or I can make it so that if the `currentVal = Target.Value`, it won't append it. This just means that you won't be able to paste the same thing in multiple times.

Comment: @Jeeped just noticed you were active on my first question when I first found out VBA existed and then came here with a "Please do my work for me" question. lol

Comment: @urdearboy - It seems you've come a long way in a short period of time.

Comment: you guys so wholesome @Jeeped

Comment: Also, regarding this old answer, can't you just click on the cell editor at the top of the spreadsheet and paste the info in there? sigh at my slow self : p

Comment: @user1274820 thanks for putting up with this post. I have since learned VBA and can only imagine how frustrating this post was lulz

Comment: That was too tedious for what I was trying to do (dummy proof it for co-workers). Ended up automating it a different way with data validation, and VBA to hide/show certain rows with text given the validation. This worked since *copy* only grabs visible cells. @user1274820